# awk script to extract the argument of an option

Tags: awk, scripting

Can some one explain what the `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/-f/) print $(i+1)}')` part does in the following snippet

```
line='/wwws/apache/apache2.4.16w-r01/instroot/bin/httpd -f /www/csbe-int-fb-na/generated/httpd.conf -C ServerName int-b2vusii.bmwgroup.net -c PidFile /var/tmp/apache_csbe-int-fb-na/httpd.pid'
CONF=$(echo $line | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/-f/) print $(i+1)}')
```

O/p : `/www/csbe-int-fb-na/generated/httpd.conf -C`

but i need to get only `/www/csbe-int-fb-na/generated/httpd.conf`

Answer (score 4):

I've reformatted the `awk` code:

```
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if($i~/-f/)
            print $(i+1)
```

The for-loop iterates from 1 to `NF`, the number of fields in any input line.

Each field (`$i`) in the input line gets checked to see if it matches the pattern "-f", which is just a string literal.

If a field matches "-f", then the code prints out the field following the field that contains "-f".

On my a RHEL box, this ends up printing out:

```
/www/csbe-int-fb-na/generated/httpd.conf -C
```

If you look closely at the input line, there's a field that consists exactly of "-f", and indeed, `awk` prints out the next field, "/www/csbe-int-fb-na/generated/httpd.conf"  Confusingly, that field contains an embedded "-f", so on the next iteration of the for-loop, the `awk` script finds taht "/www/csbe-int-fb-na/generated/httpd.conf" contains "-f", so it prints the next field, "-C".

If all you want is the Apache configuration file, you can modify the pattern that the field must match to make it an exact match, and have the `awk` script quit after finding the "-f" field, and printing the next field.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^-f$/) {print $(i+1); exit} }'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but the same is not getting applied in the below case "line1='/wwws/apache/apache2.4.16w-r01/instroot/bin/httpd -f /www/nop-admin-web/generated/httpd.conf -C ServerName nop-admin-us-int.bmwgroup.net -c PidFile /var/tmp/apac
he_nop-admin-web/httpd.pid'
CONF=$(echo $line | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/-f/) print $(i+1)}')
"
O/P : /www/nop-admin-web/generated/httpd.conf

Comment: @VinayThupili - You set a value of `line1`, but the example code has `echo $line`.  You need to use consistent variable naming.

Comment: Sorry it was "CONF=$(echo $line1 | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/-f/) print $(i+1)}')"

Comment: @VinayThupili - so if works once you do `echo $line`, correct?

Comment: @VinayThupili, add double quotes around the variable:  `echo "$line1"`.  Also you should add double quotes around the whole command substitution: `"$(echo "$line1" | awk '...')"`  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/135943

Comment: `$i~/^-f$/` could be made clearer as `$i == "-f"`